# erro no full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Eu tenho um calendário completo e quando eu mudo o idioma para portugues, ele me retorna esse erro. 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defineLocale' of undefined

```
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek'
                },
                defaultView: 'month',
                viewRender: function (view) {
                    var title = view.title;
                    $(".taskElementCalendar").html(title);
                }
            });

            $(".taskElementPrev").click(function () {
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('prev');
            });
            $(".taskElementNext").click(function () {
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('next');
            });
            $(".taskElementToday").click(function () {
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('today');
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você importou corretamente o locale específico?

De acordo com a documentação:

> **How to use other locales**
>
> You will need to load the locale JavaScript data file in order to use
>   it. These files are included with the FullCalendar download in the
>   locale/ directory. They must be loaded via a  tag after the
>   main FullCalendar library is loaded.

```
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/locale/es.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        });

    });

</script>
```

Se você importar o locale específico, não é necessário passar nenhuma option.

Agora se você importar o arquivo JS que possui todos os locais, então você pode colocar a options `locale` quando estiver inicializando o fullCalendar.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/locale-all.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            locale: 'es'
        });

    });

</script>
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Qualquer dúvida, é só comentar.